# how to check a point if it lies inside a rectangle

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a rectangle Rect (x,y,w,h) and a point P (px, py).
x and y are the top left coordinate of the rectangle.
w is it's width.
h is it's height.
px and py are the coordinate of the point P.
Does anyone knows the algorithm to check if P lies inside Rect.
Surprisingly, I couldn't find any correct answer for my question on the internet.
Much appreciate!

Comment: x<px && px< (x+w) && y < py && py < (y+h)

Comment: thanks a lot @QuentinUK, I tried and it's working well now

Comment: Interestingly, the convention for `y` of @QuentinUK (that you thanked) is the opposite of that of the accepted answer.

Comment: Is it a mathematical coordinate system with y axis going up or a computer coordinate system with y going down? Are the coordinates pixels with pixel width or infinitesimally thin? Are the borders inside the rectangle or not or only some borders? E.g. x yes, x+w not?

Comment: There are lots of possibilities. Sometimes left and top and not inside the rectangle but right and bottom are. Sometimes the y-co-ordinate is inverted. A rectangle's corner could be top-left or bottom-left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point P(px, py) lies inside the Rectangle with top left pt. coordinates (x,y) and width and height w&h respectively if both the conditions satisfy:

- x < px < (x+w)
- y > py > (y-h)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It depends on the definition of coordinate system. For the ones usually used in graphics programming y axis goes down, so condition for `py` would be analogous to the one for `px`, i.e. `y < py < y+h` (or `<=` in all cases, depending on the definition of "inside").

Answer (score 0):

It's just a metter of checking that `x` is within the rectangle left and right sides and that `y` is within top and bottom:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    double x, y;
};

struct Rect {
    double x, y, w, h;
    
    bool contains(const Point& p) {
        return p.x >= x && p.y >= y && p.x <= x+w && p.y <= y+h;
    }
};

int main() {
    Rect r({ 3,4,5,8 });
    std::cout << r.contains({ 3.2, 7.3 });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x, y, w, h;
  std::cin >> x >> y >> w >> h;
      
  int px, py;
  std::cin >> px >> py;
  
  if(px >= x && px <= (x + w) && py <= y && py >= (y - h))
    std::cout << "point is in the rectangle";
  else
    std::cout << "point is out of the rectangle";
}
```

Comment: Why do you assume that `h` should be subtracted from `y`. Logically it should behave as `w`, so being added to `y`.

Comment: @Costantino Grana Because point is on the top left

Comment: @Costantino Grana for example if the given point of rectangle(x, y) was on the top right then we have below conditions: x-w <= px <= x and y-h <= py <= y

Comment: It is a matter of definition of the coordinate system. The conditions have to match, each could be right.